# Почему ЛУНА-парк?

Tags: этимология

Парки аттракционов называют еще луна-парками. А почему так? При чем к аттракционам луна?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лунопарк (англ. Luna park) — разновидность парка развлечений, несколько аттракционов, собранных в одном месте. Получил своё название вслед за первым Луна-парком, который был назван по названию корабля, участвовавшего в аттракционе «Полёт на Луну»; корабль был назван «Луна» в честь Луны Данди, сестры одного из создателей парка Элмера Данди;
Первый луна-парк в России был открыт в мае 1912 года в Санкт-Петербурге на Офицерской улице (ныне улица Декабристов) дом № 39. Построен английской компанией на деньги русского миллионера. Луна-парк Санкт-Петербурга выполнен в таком же стиле, как и луна-парк Лондона. В 1924 году луна-парк разобрали, и теперь на его месте находится стадион НГУ имени П. Ф. Лесгафта, Санкт-Петербург

Источник-Вики.

Comment: >несколько аттракционов, собранных в одном месте.

А то, что такой парк **передвижной**, это обязательный атрибут?

Я замечал, что местные парки с аттракционами, насколько мне встречались, не имеют в своём названии "луна". 

А вот приезжающие на некоторое время в город аттракционы -- это обычно луна-парки.

Comment: Слово ПЕРЕДВИЖНОЙ никакой роли не играет, местные парки просто не дотягивают до Луна-парка - там такие аттракционы, как "Комната страха", "У Дракона","Колесо обозрения", "Железная дорога", в первом был "Полёт на Луну",в общем, по последнему слову науки и техники, праздничное оформление наподобие ярмарки, много огней.Передвижные тоже пытаются привезти с собой что-то особенное, иначе кто к ним пойдёт?...